# How to copy a file from my SSH server to my desktop

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

How do you copy a file to your desktop from SSH server on Ubuntu?

Comment: -1 for not showing any research effort and being too ambiguous. What are the operating systems involved on both sides? Is it Ubuntu → Windows? Windows → Ubuntu? Ubuntu → Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6):

SCP is probably the easiest way:

```
scp username@server.com:remote/path/to/file.txt ~/local/path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

If your Desktop is Windows-based, use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net).

> WinSCP is an open source free SFTP client, SCP client, FTPS client and FTP client for Windows. Its main function is file transfer between a local and a remote computer. Beyond this, WinSCP offers scripting and basic file manager functionality.
>
> [image]

Comment: Or the PuTTY version of scp - pscp.